# Ionic2 Input boxes are having different sizes on Login

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

Can you help me to solve this issue? You can see this password input box have a bigger line.How can I make both same sizes?

[**Here is the Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CClbhn) : just see the `page1.ts` file

```
<ion-content padding class="page1">
  <ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>

<div padding>
  <button block>Sign In</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Cheers :)

We just need to remove the outer `<ion-list>` element.This is a bug and I have reported it.Hope Ionic team will give a solution.I have extracted above from the [**Ionic doc here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#floating-labels).

```
<ion-content padding class="page1">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<div padding>
  <button block>Sign In</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

You can read more about this here: [**Ionic git repo**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10881)